# Angular service constructor is being triggered before APP_INITIALIZER can finish

Tags: angular

I seem to have a race condition between a root provided service and APP_INITIALIZER in my app, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I want to ensure the APP_INITIALIZER finishes first, as the service being triggered relies on an AppConfig that the APP_INITIALIZER is supposed to set up. Since the constructor is triggering first it's using an undefined value and throwing an error.

I have simplified the implementation of AppInitService, but the principal is the same. I want the promise returned by `init` to resolve before the UserSerialService constructor is called. Currently the constructor is being called first and is causing an error, which means the `init` promise never completes.

Service being constructed

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserSerialService {

  public userSerial$: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  private _urlPrefix = '/cldflt/user/api/user/my-serial';

  constructor(private _configService: AppConfigService,
              private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.getUserSerial$().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
      this.userSerial$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(res.body.serial)
    })
  }

  public getUserSerial$ = (): Observable<HttpResponse<Serial>> => {
    const url = this._configService.getConfig().baseUrl + `${this._urlPrefix}`;
    return this._http.get<any>(url, { observe: 'response' });
  }
}
```

NgModule

```
export function initApp(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  console.log("InitApp called");
  return () => appInitService.init();

}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initApp,
      deps: [AppInitService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppInitService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInitService {

  constructor(private _configService: AppConfigService,
              private _splitService: SplitIOService) { }

  init(): Promise<void>{
    console.log("InitApp called");
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      console.log("Promise complete");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use UserSerialService?

Comment: @BojanKogoj In a couple of other services, and also the constructor of `app.component`. What I can't figure out is why it's being triggered in the first place, since `app.component` isn't supposed to construct until APP_INITIALIZER has finished.

Comment: By any chance in SplitIOService?

Comment: @BojanKogoj Yes, that's exactly where. It's all just became apparent. Is there anyway I can force a specific order in which these services are constructed? I need the AppConfigService first, then the UserSerialService, and then finally the SplitIOService

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, because AppConfigService requires UserSerialService. You can and try to split UserSerialService

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you to refactor your code to handle asynchronicity in right way, in that case you won't care about orde of execution;

```ts
class AppConfigService {
  config$ = new ReplaySubject<Configuration>(1);
  setConfig(config: Configuration) {this.config$.next(config)}
  getConfig(): Observable<Configuration> {return this.config$}
}
```

```ts
class UserSerialService {
  // ...
  public getUserSerial$ = (): Observable<HttpResponse<Serial>> => {
    return this._configService.getConfig().pipe(switchMap(({baseUrl}) => 
          this._http.get<any>(url, { observe: 'response' })
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the AppConfigService as it's part of a shared library, which means its structure needs to stay as is. Is there any other way I can force a specific order of construction/execution?

Comment: I believe it can be done, but it is a bit ugly. I'll create a separate answer with example

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a Subject to emit a signal when the initialization is done and subscribe in the other service and chain the two observables together by mergeMap etc?

Answer (score 0):

you could inject your `_splitService` later, so it would be constructed later as well as its dependency `UserSerialService`

```
export class AppInitService {

  constructor(private _configService: AppConfigService,
              private injector: Injector) { }

  init(): Promise<void>{
    console.log("InitApp called");
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      console.log("Promise complete");
    });
  }

  doSomething() {
     const splitService = this.injector.get(SplitIOService);
     splitService.youAreNoLongerAProblem();
  }
}
```